How to populate columns only where they match row value in another set of columns?
I'm trying to iterate through a subset of a dataframe and see if the value in the row matches a column heading in the main df. In the examples below I've reduced the number of columns but in the real dataset there are 20+ random columns. The order of the columns also won't be uniform so there's no guarantee that '1' will match to 'a'. It needs to iterate through all rows and all columns to see if any one row matches any one column name.
Example df-
example df
I want the output to look like this-
ideal output
It's important to note the order of the columns at the start will not always be the same, it's likely to change and become more or less.
I've tried for loops and iterrows() but I'm having trouble getting just the row value and comparing it to the list of columns later on (list = ['a','b','c','d']).
Update: This is what I've got now incorporating Alex's answer-
def checkCol(num_col):
    for letter_col in list:
        df[letter_col] = df[num_col].apply(lambda x: "x" if x == letter_col else pd.NA)

for num_col in num_col_list:
    checkCol(num_col)

Unfortunately the lambda is overwriting itself each time and I can't figure out a way for it to either skip, or just keep the current value of the row if it's already populated.

When posting data like a table, please provide it in text form rather than as an image.

I've provided an answer below. If this is incompatible with the details of your question, please update your question to make it clearer what you are asking for.

Welcome to SO. Please familiarise yourself with how to ask a good question and provide a minimal reproducible example.

Here's something that may answer your question:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "1": ["a", "a", "a", None],
        "2": ["b", None, "b", None],
        "3": ["impact", "a", None, None],
        "4": [None, "d", None, "d"],
        "a": [pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA],
        "b": [pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA],
        "c": [pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA],
        "d": [pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA],
    }
)

df["a"] = df["1"].apply(lambda x: "x" if x == "a" else pd.NA)
df["b"] = df["2"].apply(lambda x: "x" if x == "b" else pd.NA)
df["c"] = df["3"].apply(lambda x: "x" if x == "c" else pd.NA)
df["d"] = df["4"].apply(lambda x: "x" if x == "d" else pd.NA)

print(df)
#       1     2       3     4     a     b     c     d
# 0     a     b  impact  None     x     x  <NA>  <NA>
# 1     a  None       a     d     x  <NA>  <NA>     x
# 2     a     b    None  None     x     x  <NA>  <NA>
# 3  None  None    None     d  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     x


The lambda part works well thanks, but I need to iterate through the entire dataframe as I mentioned in the post. The order of the columns also won't be uniform (I'll update the post to add that) so there's no guarantee that '1' will match to 'a'. It needs to iterate through all rows and all columns to see if any one row matches any one column name. I've written a function using your code and put it in a for loop but currently the lambda is replacing itself and leaving all NAs so I'll work on it. Thanks!

You can use a dictionary to map the numeric column name and string value.
For example:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "1": ["a", "a", "a", None],
        "2": ["b", None, "b", None],
        "3": ["impact", "a", None, None],
        "4": [None, "d", None, "d"],
        "a": [pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA],
        "b": [pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA],
        "c": [pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA],
        "d": [pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA],
    }
)

map_strs = {'1': 'a',
           '2': 'b',
           '3': 'c',
           '4': 'd'}

def checkCol(num_col):
    df[map_strs[num_col]] = df[num_col].apply(lambda x: "x" if x == map_strs[num_col] else pd.NA)

Then, you can use keys to iterate through columns, and it's values to replace with x in string columns.
for num_col in map_strs.keys():
    checkCol(num_col)

